# Как хранить юнитов в листе, при создании разных экземпляров классов?

Tags: c#, winforms

В общем, у меня есть 10 юнитов, я их создаю в одной в классе, автоматически по сути в конструкторе формы, потом открываю другую форму и там добавляю ещё одного юнита или 2-х, закрываю форму создания и открываю снова первую форму и соответственно в первом снова вызывается конструктор и кол-во юнитов вновь становится = 10, как и было ранее, а мой созданный юнит 11-ый удаляется, он же из другого экземпляра формы, подскажите где хранить этих юнитов, чтобы они не удалялись?

вот сервис

```cs
public class AppService : IAppService
{
    public List<ServerUser> Users;

    public List<ServerUser> MakeList()
    {
        ServerUser AlexUser = new ServerUser()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Alex",
            SecondName = "Vasilich",
            NameOfFamily = "Melentyev",
            Age = 26,
            Faculty = "ITS",
            Course = 9,
        };
        ServerUser JeffUser = new ServerUser()
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Jeff",
            SecondName = "Big",
            NameOfFamily = "lebowski",
            Age = 126,
            Faculty = "no",
            Course = 10,
        };
        ServerUser PetrUser = new ServerUser()
        {
            Id = 3,
            Name = "Petr",
            SecondName = "First",
            NameOfFamily = "Romanov",
            Age = 235,
            Faculty = "Shipbuilding",
            Course = 36,
        };
        ServerUser ChubaisUser = new ServerUser()
        {
            Id = 4,
            Name = "Anatoly",
            SecondName = "Борисович",
            NameOfFamily = "Chubais",
            Age = 65,
            Faculty = "Faculty of Nanotechnology",
            Course = 36,
        };
        ServerUser PutinUser = new ServerUser()
        {
            Id = 5,
            Name = "V.V.",
            SecondName = "Krasavchik",
            NameOfFamily = "Putin",
            Age = 68,
            Faculty = "Faculty of Longevity",
            Course = 36,
        };
        ServerUser CooperUser = new ServerUser()
        {
            Id = 6,
            Name = "Sheldon",
            SecondName = "Li",
            NameOfFamily = "Cooper",
            Age = 30,
            Faculty = "Faculty of Physics",
            Course = 136,
        };
        ServerUser StrycaloUser = new ServerUser()
        {
            Id = 7,
            Name = "Yura",
            SecondName = "--",
            NameOfFamily = "Kaplan",
            Age = 65,
            Faculty = "Faculty of Music",
            Course = 36,
        };
        ServerUser MessiUser = new ServerUser()
        {
            Id = 8,
            Name = "Lionel",
            SecondName = "Andreas",
            NameOfFamily = "Messi",
            Age = 65,
            Faculty = "Faculty of Footabll",
            Course = 36,
        };
        ServerUser TalUser = new ServerUser()
        {
            Id = 9,
            Name = "Michail",
            SecondName = "Nehemevich",
            NameOfFamily = "Tal",
            Age = 65,
            Faculty = "Faculty of Chess",
            Course = 36,
        };
        ServerUser NoNameUser = new ServerUser()
        {
            Id = 10,
            Name = "NoName",
            SecondName = "NoSecondName",
            NameOfFamily = "NoNameOfFamily",
            Age = 65,
            Faculty = "no",
            Course = 36,
        };

        Users = new List<ServerUser>();
        Users.Add(AlexUser);
        Users.Add(JeffUser);
        Users.Add(PetrUser);
        Users.Add(ChubaisUser);
        Users.Add(PutinUser);
        Users.Add(CooperUser);
        Users.Add(StrycaloUser);
        Users.Add(MessiUser);
        Users.Add(TalUser);
        Users.Add(NoNameUser);

        return Users;

    }

    public ServerUser[] GetInfoAboutUsersByAge(int age, ServerUser[] users)
    {

        var tempList = new List<ServerUser>();

        var tempList2 = users.Where(u => u.Age == age).ToList();

        ServerUser[] usersArr = tempList2.ToArray<ServerUser>();

        return usersArr;
    }

    private ServerUser[] ConvertToUsersArr(List<ServerUser> users)
    {
        ServerUser[] massiv = users.ToArray<ServerUser>();
        return massiv;


    }

    public ServerUser[] GetInfoAboutUsersByCourse(int course, ServerUser[] users)
    {
        var tempList = new List<ServerUser>();
        tempList = users.Where(u => u.Course == course).ToList();

        ServerUser[] usersArr = tempList.ToArray<ServerUser>();

        return usersArr;

    }

    public ServerUser[] GetInfoAboutUsersByFaculty(string faculty, ServerUser[] users)
    {
        var tempList = new List<ServerUser>();

        tempList = users.Where(u => u.Faculty == faculty).ToList();

        ServerUser[] usersArr = tempList.ToArray<ServerUser>();


        return usersArr;
    }

    public ServerUser GetInfoAboutUsersByNum(int num, ServerUser[] users)
    {
        var user = users.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Id == num);
        return user;
    }

    public ServerUser ShowInfoAboutUsersByName(string name, ServerUser[] users)
    {
        var user = users.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == name);

        return user;
    }

    string IAppService.ShowInfoAboutUsers()
    {
        string all = string.Empty;
        foreach (var user in Users)
        {
            all += $"Name: {user.Name} Second Name: {user.SecondName} Name Of Family: {user.NameOfFamily} Faculty: {user.Faculty} Age: {user.Age} Course: {user.Course}";
            all += "\n";
        }
        return all;
    }

    public ServerUser Edit(int id, string name, string secondName, string nameOfFamily, string faculty, int age, int course)
    {
        int nextId = id;
        ServerUser newUser = new ServerUser()
        {
            Id = nextId,
            Name = name,
            SecondName = secondName,
            NameOfFamily = nameOfFamily,
            Faculty = faculty,
            Age = age,
            Course = course
        };

        return newUser;
    }

    public ServerUser Save(int countUsers, string name, string secondName, string nameOfFamily, string faculty, int age, int course)
    {
        ServerUser newUser = new ServerUser()
        {
            Id = ++countUsers,
            Name = name,
            SecondName = secondName,
            NameOfFamily = nameOfFamily,
            Faculty = faculty,
            Age = age,
            Course = course
        };
        return newUser;
    }

    public ServerUser DeleteId(int num, ServerUser[] users)
    {
        var user = users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == num);
        return user;
    }

    public List<string> ShowFaculties(ServerUser[] users)
    {
        List<string> Faculies = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in users)
        {
            if (!Faculies.Contains(item.Faculty))
            {
                Faculies.Add(item.Faculty);
            }
        }
        return Faculies;
    }
}
```

Вот клиент

```cs
public partial class FormStudents : Form
{
    AppService AppService = new AppService();
    AppServiceClient client;
    CreateForm create;

    public FormStudents()
    {
        client = new AppServiceClient();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private List<ServerUser> UpdateTbl(List<ServerUser> users)
    {
        List<ServerUser> users2 = new List<ServerUser>();
        if (users.Count > 0)
        {


            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                users2.Add(user);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("users not found");
        }
        return users2;
    }


    private void btnSearchAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvStudents.DataSource = UpdateTbl(AppService.Users);
    }

    private ServerUser[] ConvertToUsersArr()
    {
        ServerUser[] massiv = AppService.Users.ToArray<ServerUser>();
        return massiv;
    }

    private void btnSearchId_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServerUser serU = new ServerUser();
        List<ServerUser> lU = new List<ServerUser>();

        try
        {
            serU = client.GetInfoAboutUsersByNum(int.Parse(tbId.Text), ConvertToUsersArr());

            lU.Add(serU);

            dgvStudents.DataSource = lU;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("incorrectly filled fields");

        }

        ClearFields();
    }

    private void ClearFields()
    {
        tbName.Clear();
        tbSecName.Clear();
        tbNameOfFam.Clear();
        tbFac.Clear();
        tbId.Clear();
        tbAge.Clear();
        tbCourse.Clear();
    }

    private void btnSearchName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServerUser serU = new ServerUser();
        List<ServerUser> lU = new List<ServerUser>();

        serU = client.ShowInfoAboutUsersByName(tbName.Text, ConvertToUsersArr());

        if (serU != null)
        {
            lU.Add(serU);

            dgvStudents.DataSource = lU;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("incorrectly filled fields");
        }

        ClearFields();
    }

    private void btgSearchAge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServerUser[] lU;
        try
        {
            dgvStudents.DataSource = lU = client.GetInfoAboutUsersByAge(int.Parse(tbAge.Text), ConvertToUsersArr());

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("incorrectly filled fields");
        }
        ClearFields();
    }

    private void btnSearchCourse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServerUser serU = new ServerUser();
        ServerUser[] lU;
        try
        {

            dgvStudents.DataSource = lU = (client.GetInfoAboutUsersByCourse(int.Parse(tbCourse.Text), ConvertToUsersArr()));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("incorrectly filled fields");
        }
        ClearFields();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServerUser serU = new ServerUser();
        ServerUser[] lU;
        try
        {
            dgvStudents.DataSource = lU = client.GetInfoAboutUsersByFaculty(comboBoxFac.SelectedItem.ToString(), ConvertToUsersArr());
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("incorrectly filled fields");
        }
        ClearFields();
    }

    private void btnGoToCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        create = new CreateForm();
        create.Show();
    }

    private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppService.MakeList();
        comboBoxFac.DataSource = AppService.ShowFaculties(ConvertToUsersArr());
    }
}
```

И вторая форма

```cs
public partial class CreateForm : Form
{
    AppService AppService = new AppService();
    AppServiceClient client;
    FormStudents fs = new FormStudents();

    public CreateForm()
    {
        AppService.MakeList();
        client = new AppServiceClient();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ClearFields()
    {
        tbName.Clear();
        tbSecName.Clear();
        tbNameOfFam.Clear();
        tbFac.Clear();
        tbAge.Clear();
        tbCourse.Clear();
    }

    private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //WriteInToFile();
        string Name = tbName.Text;
        string SecondName = tbSecName.Text;
        string NameOfFamily = tbNameOfFam.Text;
        string Faculty = tbFac.Text;
        string Age = tbAge.Text;
        string Course = tbCourse.Text;
        try
        {

            AppService.Users.Add(client.Save(AppService.Users.Count, Name, SecondName, NameOfFamily, Faculty, int.Parse(Age), int.Parse(Course)));
            ClearFields();
            MessageBox.Show($"student with name {Name} created");

            //usersTbl.ItemsSource = UpdateTbl(service.Users);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("incorrectly filled fields");
        }
    }

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        fs.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите хоть какие-то фрагменты кода, где и что у вас происходит. А вообще вам нужно хранить экземпляр первой формы и восстанавливать его, а не создавать заново, как-то так. Либо сделать лист юнитов статическим

Comment: Его слишком много, просто если бы у меня была бд, я бы хранил юнитов в бд и не было бы проблем, но задание такоенужно хранить в классе, как это обычно делается? Я добавляю юнита, а когда создаётся новый экз класса (формы), то мой юнит соотвыетственно исчезает

Comment: что значит восстанавливать?

Comment: Нужно вызывать новую форму примерно так ```form.ShowDialog(this);```, тогда новая форма будет знать о том, какая форма ее породила, будет заполнено свойство Parent, из которого можно и восстановить обратно первую форму

Comment: добавил код, там wcf сервис и два клиента, проблема с winform

Comment: В классе ```FormStudents``` создаете форму как ```create.Show(this);```. Во втором классе не создаете новую FormStudents, а восстанавливаете ее из свойства ```Owner.Show(); this.Hide();```

Comment: не помогло юнитов по прежнему 10

Comment: Вам нужно также AppService не создавать в новой форме, а передать через конструктор из старой итд., все что вы используете уже созданное не надо создавать заново

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такая штука - внедрение зависимости, или Dependency Injection (DI). Звучит страшно, но на деле работает очень просто. Самая популярная разновидность DI - Constructor Injection, то есть просто вызов конструктора дочернего класса с аргументами.

Покажу на простом примере: к примеру у вас есть 2 формы, форма 1 - главная, показывает дочернюю форму. С точки зрения ООП у вас есть ошибка, вы каждый раз пересоздаете вторую форму при этом не закрывая её после использвоания в предыдущий раз. Прятать основную форму необязательно, достаточно использовать вызов дочерней формы как диалога.

К примеру у вас есть класс данных.

```cs
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Главная форма имеет коллекцию с этими юзерами и как-то его загружает

```cs
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private List<User> _users;

    private void LoadUsers()
    {
        _users = LoadUsersFromServer(); // здесь может быть любой код загрузки
    }
}
```

И есть дочерняя форма, которая этот список хочет редактировать. И чтобы список принять, сделаю так, чтобы конструктор дочерней формы мог принимать этот список в себя как аргумент.

```cs
public partial class EditForm : Form
{
    private List<User> _users;

    public EditForm(List<User> users)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _users = users;
    }
}
```

Тогда вызов и передача данных из главной формы дочерней будет выглядеть так

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form dialog = new EditForm(_users); // cписок _users передается с помощью Constructor Injection в дочернюю форму
    if (dialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // дочерняя форма закрыта, список наверное изменился
    }
}
```

Всё. Теперь дочерняя форма может работать со тем же самым списком `_users`.

Чтобы вернуть правильный `DialogResult`, назначьте его значение кнопкам в дочерней форме, при этом вам больше не понадобится вызывать `.Hide()`. При нажатии на кнопку форма закроется сама и вернет тот `DialogResult`, который назначен кнопке в дизайнере. Вы даже обработчики событий этих кнопок можете убрать из кода.

Кстати при вызове диалога таким образом вам открываются всякие визуальные фишки, например если вы дочерней форме зададите `StartPosition` как `CenterParent`, то она появится ровно по центру родительской формы.

Comment: попробую, а подскажите public CreateForm(Form parent, List<User> users) : base(parent) парент и форм парент это имя родительской формы просто?

Comment: @АлексейМелентьев это ссылка на нее, да, это по сути родительская форма. Механизмы Winforms запишут ее в свойство `Parent` автоматически. Вы можете получить ее в коде `MainForm mainForm = (MainForm)Parent;` и обращаться к ее публичным свойствам и методам. Если ответ окажется полезным, не забудьте отметить его галочкой.

Comment: да, спасибо, очень полезно, но только до меня всё же не дошло я сделал так: public CreateForm(FormStudents, List<ServerUser> users) : base(FormStudents)
        {
            _users = users;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

Comment: но FormStudents подчеркивает красным... не понимаю как нужно написать у мееня форм студентс и есть родительская форма

Comment: @АлексейМелентьев `CreateForm(Form parent, List<ServerUser> users) : base(parent)` в этом месте совершенно все равно, какой конкретный тип у формы-родителя, достаточно ее принять как базовый тип `Form`. Учите ООП, вам этих знаний вот прямо сейчас не хватает, в частности знаний о наследовании.

Comment: теперь base ругается, что нет конструктора с 1 аргументом, то есть в родительском классе в конструкторе должен быть аргумент, а что туда передать? В вашем примеере я так понимаю в LoadUsers что-то должно было быть... Может туда передать сам список users?

Comment: @АлексейМелентьев прошу прощения, запутался, исправил ответ. Нужно вызывать `ShowDialog(this)`, а не конструктор формы.

Comment: ура! Спасибо всё заработало, как у кота Матроскина. Спасибо очень помог!

Comment: @АлексейМеленьев не за что. Учите ООП, дальше будет только сложнее без этих знаний.

Comment: @АлексейМеленьев [и вот это ещё](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ)